# Angular2 css file with class conflict

Tags: css, angular, encapsulation

I use 2 css file but in these two file, i have a class with the same name... I use one in a component and the second in an another component.

How use these CSS file to have no more conflict ?

Thx in advance !

Comment: Both component applies different CSS files? Can you provide some more detail ?

Comment: Hey ! Thx for interesting to my problem ! So, I have two component. And 2 css file with same name class inside. Each component use only one css file. If i start my application on Component 1, the style is good. But when i go in the component 2 this one took the style of the component 1. And vice versa if i start on the Component 2.

Comment: Can't you use `styleUrl` ang give CSS to it ?

Comment: Yes, but, i already do that ! Another detail is Component 1 and Component 2 use many component to works. So I give css with styleUrl and i set encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None to "distribute" css to these component

Comment: Please create a plunkr and provide some code. And whatever you have mentioned in the also update in your question.

Comment: i also have same problem else or it is good idea to create two angular project for admin panel or other components.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

1. Change class name. Instead of have 2 classes called `myClass`, make `myClassUsers` and `myClassClients`, for example.
2. Change the way you reference them to be more precise, making use of other classes that are actually unique to each component. Example:

*CSS file 1:*

```
div.comp1Class > table > tr.myClass {...}
```

*CSS file 2:*

```
div.comp2Class > table > tr.myClass {...}
```

*Instead of having in both:*

```
.myClass {...}
```

Comment: I think about it... But... It's very ... very... very long because the first css file make 10000 line and the second 6000 line... :/

Comment: @N.Panchout Do both Components really need both CSS files? If not, load CSS file 1 to Component 1 and CSS file 2 to component 2.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing ! It's work but  if i go to the component 1 at first and i go to the component 2 then. The component 2 take the css file of the component 1 ... And vice versa

Comment: @N.Panchout It's hard to understand with no code shown whatsoever. Please add your component's code in the OP and I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply a more specific selector?
Specific selector takes precedence over a less specific one.

Eg. For Component XYZ, the selector in CSS will be
.xyz .common-class-name{
Code goes here
}
And for Component ABC, the selector in CSS will be
.abc .common-class-name{
Code goes here
}
That way you can resolve this issue.

Comment: I think about it... But... It's very ... very... very long because the first css file make 10000 line and the second 6000 line... :/