# Conflicting class name in CSS

Tags: css, materialize, flickity

I am using materializeCSS to build a website and it already has a class called carousel. However, I wish to use carousel from [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) and I wanted to know what would happen if I include both files in an html.

This question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030395/angular2-css-file-with-class-conflict) but the answers do not satisfy my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the flickity carousel on github ( https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/blob/master/dist/flickity.css ) and it appears to me that everything in the css starts with .flickity- so it shouldn't be a problem.

You're probably talking about this part found on their site:

```
$('.main-carousel').flickity({
  // options
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true
});
```

That `.main-carousel` could be anything you want, as long as it matches with the class you use in your markup:

```
<div class="main-carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering what would happen if both both had classes with same name with no distinction whatsoever. Would there be a sort of priority?

Comment: For the same selector specifity, the last one is the one who wins.